# Code that will display a warning before it will finally delete records

Tags: php, html, web

so here is my code for deleting records in the database

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

header("location:display.php");

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("bfp6",$con);

$result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM station WHERE id<>234");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

What code should i add in order for it to display a warning that says "all records will be deleted, continue?" Then there is a yes and cancel options. when i click yes it will delete everything except for the one with id=234 and when i click cancel it will not do anything.I really don't have idea with this or even if it is possible. please help me out guys.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for a client side javascript. You can use native confirm dialog in this way:

```
<a href="delete.php" onclick="return confirm('All records will be deleted, continue?')">Delete records</a>
```

Once you click "Yes" browser will navigate to your script deleting records.